# How to dynamically use upsert in ADF to an Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Inside of my pipeline, I'm running a lookup to gather tables from one database to transfer to another.

```
select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'schema1' OR TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema2'
```

Then I do a copy activity for each of those tables. And at the moment I've got the sink option set to "insert". However, I would like to try and use upsert, but I've got to identify "key column(s)" in order to do so. What's the best way to try and get these dynamically? And which columns are best used for this? Columns that will contain a unique value for that row?

Answer (score 1):

For the key columns, you need to use a column or combination of columns that uniquely identify a row in that table.

You can add this key list to the result of the query above, either by getting them from metadata (if you have a primary key or a unique index on that table), or by keeping them in some management table, and querying that table.

Then you can use dynamic content in ADF to provide the key columns on the sink tab. Please note that the key column should be of type array (because its a list of columns).

Comment: Thank you Chen, I'm glad I was on the right track. I checked to see if these tables had primary key constraints that I could just add to the lookup query I was running, unfortunately they do not. The only other real option here is to create a management table- like you suggested- and define the key columns myself for each table, correct?

Comment: Yes, if there are no keys defined, you will need to create your own manage table.

Comment: Thank you. I plan on looking at these tables, finding a column and run a unique value count on it. If it matches the same number of total rows in the table, then it's safe to use that column as a key column here, would that be a correct way of looking at it?

Also, when I go to parameterize the key columns inside of my sink, would I do it like so: ```@item().key_column``` ? My schemas and tables are defined this way, but they are guaranteed to have only one value (whereas I could define multiple key columns), so do I need to do something different here?

Comment: @BlakeB9, the value that you pass to key columns should look like this: ["key1","key2"] . Its an array of the keys.

Comment: Hey Chen, How would I accomplish creating an array in the dynamic content? I've identified all key columns in a management table and joined it with my original lookup query. I want to do something like ```@createArray(@item().key_columns)``` however that does not work.

Comment: Simply store it in the management table in an array format: ["key1","key2"] . And then use @item.key_columns to pass it to dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

Create database linked services for Look Up, Source and Destination Create pipeline and perform look up activity to get list of tables in source database with query option using below query.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
```

After successful execution of lookup connect foreach activity enable sequential and add `@activity('Lookup1').output.value` as dynamic content to the for each add look up activity to foreach with query execution using below query to get key column of tables

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
```

after successful execution of lookup connect copy data activity create Source sql dataset with created linked and create two parameters named Schema and tableName to retrieve tables of database and given below values:

```
schema: @item().TABLE_SCHEMA
tableName: @item().TABLE_NAME
```

Create sink dataset and create above parameters and give same value. Enable upsert option and add dynamic content as `@createArray(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.column_name)` for key column

[image]

Debug the pipeline it executing successfully and updating the tables in target successfully.

[image]

Pipeline Json:

```
{
    "name": "Pipeline 2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup2",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT column_name\nFROM information_schema.key_column_usage",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable3",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy_3q5",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Source",
                                    "value": "files//input.xml"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Destination",
                                    "value": "dbo.input"
                                }
                            ],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "upsert",
                                    "upsertSettings": {
                                        "useTempDB": true,
                                        "keys": {
                                            "value": "@createArray(activity('Lookup2').output.firstRow.column_name)",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_3q5",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "tableName": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_NAME",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "schema": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_SCHEMA",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "schema": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_SCHEMA",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "tableName": {
                                            "value": "@item().TABLE_NAME",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "ok": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-04-19T11:45:57Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/pipelines"
}
```

Comment: What if I've created another table that identifies the key columns and joined it with the first lookup? I would like to do something like ```@createArray(@item().key_columns)``` I doubt that works though